# css for disabled radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

by default, when we put  **disabled="disabled"** for  `<input type="radio"`.. . it will turn grey color. what is the css i need to use the change the color ? can i do this instantly with jquery ?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189760/change-color-of-disabled-radiobutton-list-element

Answer (score 2):

styling radio buttons is not widely supported by most browser as you can see in this [test](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/radio-button/).

but if you really want it, you may try this [plugin](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/)