# Change the color of disabled radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to style the disabled radio button to exactly looks like enabled one. But still it should be uneditable.

I tried using readonly attribute but it is not working. 
I don't want to go for any custom radio buttons. Want to do it with css/javascript/jQuery

Check the image below : disabled radio button is shown with red underline and enabled with blue

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: may be duplication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191841/css-for-disabled-radio-button

Comment: You can't do that, the browser doesn't allow it. But, if you want, instead of disable it, you can use a `div` with absolute position and put it over the input

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin that is the client requirement to display disable inputs in dark black and not grey

Comment: That would be very confusing for the user; I'd try to steer your client away from that.

Comment: can't you convince your client; Its default behavior of Browsers. might be you can do that using some script but won't suggest you to use unnecessary code.

Comment: @kmsdev I saw that post but, I have the forms already developed and don't want to change the input types being rendered today looking for a quick css fix that can be pluggable easily to existing code

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin & Kheema Pandey of course I understand that, but ......... client. at least should able to convey the whether is it possible or not

Comment: There is no way to do it. You can only do that I said. You can use javascript to create the fake div.

Comment: Thanks @kmsdev. I will check how can I implement that without changing lots of stuff.

Comment: I added an answer with example code and jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, you can do it using a fake div. You need a parent element to set relative position, then, with a little javascript you can do it fast to all input elements that you want:

```
// CSS

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.disabled[disabled] {
    color: red;
}

p { position: relative; }

.input_fakediv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;    
}

// HTML

<p>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" id="milk" class="disabled" /> <label for="milk">Milk</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" id="milk" class="disabled" /> <label for="milk">Milk</label>
</p>

// JS

var $fakediv = $('<div class="input_fakediv"></div>');
$fakediv.insertAfter($('input[type="radio"]'));
```

Check it: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/Br6ek/)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I can do this, without much changes to my existing app

Comment: I will have to do the same if I want same thing with checkbox. right??

Comment: Yes, right. You have to specify the input type: `$('input[type"checkbox"]')`

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tested this in the older versions of the browsers. So in the global.css

```css
input[type="radio"]:disabled {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-clip: content-box;
    border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use CSS to accomplish this. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSEnR/1/).

Basically what you need to do is target it with

```
selector[disabled] { /* Styles here */ }
```

Comment: your disabled radio button is not looking like OP requirement.

Comment: That rule does not work. The jsfiddle css rule you used selects a label instead input

Comment: I can make the color of lable to black. But I want that round of radio button to be black. Just like enabled one

Comment: The OP specified how to target the disabled radio button, it's a HTML element and I have not seen it be customized without creating the radio button yourself.