# remove gray out from disabled radio buttons

Tags: css, radio-button

Quick question, I have a form with a series of radio buttons that are disabled if a certain user sees the form. For aesthetic reasons I would like to remove the graying out that comes by  default with the disabling.
I have tried some css but so far no success, anyone could give me a hand?

Comment: without creating custom Radio buttons? No. BTW what's the UX purpose of Disabled buttons looking like enabled?

Comment: I have done that for the ones that are yes/no, but I have a list of 5/6 with numeric values associated that the user might need to see anyway... but probably I'll go your way and see what happens :) thanx for the advice

Comment: why not hide the disabled radio buttons... better UX for sure. `input[type="radio"][disabled] { display: none; }`

Comment: Your comment below "with the current design it is hard to see if the box is checked or not" is important and shows that it is not just for "aesthetic reasons," in my opinion. One clue to an answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/67607014/2604813

Answer (score 3):

While I still dont understand the reasoning behind making a disabled radio button look clickable... I managed to get the behavior to work using jquery. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/Lkwhk/1/)

```
  $(function(){
    $('#myRadio').on('change',function(){   
        $('#myRadio').prop('checked', function(){
             return this.defaultChecked;
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Obviously, this only works when JavaScript is enabled. And then it functionally makes the radio button readonly, not disabled. The main difference is that disabled buttons give no contribution to form data; readonly buttons do.

Comment: it is just to make it look nice. with the current design it is hard to see if the box is checked or not, that's all..

Comment: I was only offering it up as a suggestion since the desired behavior really is not achieveable with CSS alone.

Comment: If going down this route it's probably easier to just listen for a `click` event then call `event.preventDefault()`.